# I have a problem in my python code to not execute correctly

Tags: python

Using the GeoJSON API

I have run this place_id = State University of New York College at Oswego in my location but the `place_id` may not match for this assignment.
my output is shown:

`ChIJEapKYeRi14kR6mYAw46fM9w`

that is not the answer.

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error  import json

serviceurl = 'http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/geojson?'

address = input('Enter location: ')

url = serviceurl + urllib.parse.urlencode({'address':address}) 
print('Retrieving', url)

uh = urllib.request.urlopen(url)  data = uh.read() 
print('Retrieved', len(data), 'characters')  #print(data.decode())

js = json.loads(data)  placeId = js['results'][0]['place_id'] 
print('Place id', placeId)
```

result showing is:

```
$ python find4.py
Enter location: State University of New York College at Oswego
Retrieving http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/geojson?address=State+University+of+New+York+College+at+Oswego
Retrieved 3720 characters
Place id ChIJEapKYeRi14kR6mYAw46fM9w
```

I expect the output of The first seven characters of the `place_id` are "ChIJdRj ..."

Comment: what makes you think that's the wrong placeId ?

Comment: At what point exactly does the program not do what it's supposed to? Use a debugger to step through the code, which is an essential skill to learn. Further, before asking here, please extract a [mcve], it is required. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

I think the output which is coming by using this code is correct. May be you are using different Json and expecting different answer because I have executed this code and It's working as per json data I am getting. I will suggest you to change the link may be then you will get your desire output.

Comment: I will change link also but i don't get result that I want